# HTML Parser for multiple input files

Tags: java, javascript, html, oracle, parsing

I want to select multiple html files at a time and extract only text using html parser and each html file will make a separate text file. Can any one suggest java code for this.

```
`FileReader f0 = new FileReader("j.html");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f0);
while((temp1=br.readLine())!=null)
  { sb.append(temp1); }
String para = sb.toString().replaceAll("<br>","\n");
String textonly = Jsoup.parse(para).text();
System.out.println(textonly);
FileWriter f1=new FileWriter("j.txt");
char buf1[] = new char[textonly.length()];
textonly.getChars(0,textonly.length(),buf1,0);
for(i=0;i<buf1.length;i++) {
 if(buf1[i]=='\n')
f1.write("\r\n");
f1.write(buf1[i]);
}`
```

I've this code but it is taking only one file at a time.I want to select multiple files.

Comment: check [jsoup.org](http://www.jsoup.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you put your code in a loop? Something like (not tested):

```
// loop over files you want to change
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
   FileReader f0 = new FileReader(i + ".html");
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f0);
   while((temp1=br.readLine())!=null) { 
      sb.append(temp1); 
   }
   String para = sb.toString().replaceAll("<br>","\n");
   String textonly = Jsoup.parse(para).text();
   System.out.println(textonly);
   // stick .txt on the end of the filename to write out
   FileWriter f1=new FileWriter(i + ".txt"); 
   char buf1[] = new char[textonly.length()];
   textonly.getChars(0,textonly.length(),buf1,0);
   for(i=0;i<buf1.length;i++) {
      if(buf1[i]=='\n') {
         f1.write("\r\n");
      }
      f1.write(buf1[i]);
   }
```

Comment: @Disko 3 Thanks for this valuable suggestion. But I've 2000 files and I've given them numbering name from 1 to 2000 as "1.html".So I want to give for loop like (i=1;i<=2000;i++) and after executing separate txt file has to generate. But I am getting errors. Can u help me.

Comment: Code changed to do that. It's just using simple string handling to construct the file names, so you may want to read up on that.

Comment: ya. I've got solution...thanx @Disko 3